# Identifying working links and not working links in selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, logging

I login to a website --> I read links from a text file(Which has working and broken links) --> I am using the HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse to detect the working and notWorking links ---Here is the main problem---> I am trying to separate the working and not working links and log into two different files. But everything goes into only one file. I am using the StatusCode property to distinguish between the two. But not successful. Please find the code below. I am very new to selenium C#.

```
public void Login()
    {
        WebDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl($"{ApplicationUrl}Login.aspx");
        WebDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id("UserName")).SendKeys(_user.Login);
        WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id("tbPassword")).SendKeys(_user.Passwort);
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = WebDriver as IJavaScriptExecutor; 
        js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", 
        WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id("LoginButton")));
        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        string fileName = @"TestFile.txt";
        // Reading the text file using StreamReader
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
        {
            String line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                WebDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(line);
                IsLinkWorking(line);
            }
            WorkingLinks.Close();
            NotWorkingLinks.Close();
        }
    } 


    public void IsLinkWorking(string line)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(line);
        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                WorkingLinks.WriteLine(WebDriver.Url);
                // Releases the resources of the response.
                response.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                NotWorkingLinks.WriteLine(WebDriver.Url);
                response.Close();
            }
        }
        catch
        { //TODO: Check for the right exception here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When HTTP status code outside of range `200-299` it will send to catch, set you code there

```
catch
{ 
    NotWorkingLinks.WriteLine(WebDriver.Url);
}
```

Comment: I checked the status code in the network mode(F12). It says 500(InternalServerError). But it does not go to the catch block.
PS: I have created an internal error in the aspx.cs page!

Comment: check if you have other blank `catch{}` block